# CSS: Why is the image not being displayed on top (z-index)?

Tags: css, z-index

I have a list, like this:

```
<ul id="categoryTabsId" class="categoryTabs">
    <li onclick="tabs(this);" class="selected" id="tab1">
       <span class="tab-one">
           <img src="http://www.dot.ca.gov/hq/jobs/images/number1_icon.jpg" />    
       </span>
       some text
    </li>
</ul>
```

The CSS which manipulates the image position is:

```
position: relative;
top: 0;
left: -20px;
```

The CSS moves the image to the right position, but the image is not displayed completely, it seems a part of the image is behind something else. I tried using z-index: 999999999 but this wont change a thing. Why is the image not on top of everything with such a high z-index?

Thanks!

Comment: Since we can't see all the corresponding code, check the z-index values of the parents and their siblings. Even if your img has a z-index of 99999, its parent might still have a z-index of -1

Comment: are you sure that the ul, li or span don't have an overflow hidden, that will hide the part of the image ?

Comment: try to add z-index to <ul> style and then add z-index to img style more than <ul>.

Comment: without the code around that (HTML AND CSS) it will not be possible to help you effectively.

Comment: I tried: "try to add z-index to <ul> style and then add z-index to img style more than <ul>"

Did not work ...

Comment: My <ul> had overflow:hidden, as mentioned above! **SOLVED**, big thanks!

Comment: If you've answered your own question, please either delete it or post the answer and accept it.